# Dev environment does not set in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

In my `_ss_environment.php` I have: `define('SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'dev');` and in my `_config.php`: `require_once("conf/ConfigureFromEnv.php");` but for some reason my environment is still in live mode and cannot change to dev. I tested with simple function below:

```
 function display(){
  if (Director::isDev()){
    echo 'yes dev'; 
  } else {
    echo 'no not dev';
  }

}

display();
```

I need the dev environment because I'm loading extra css if its in dev. It might be something silly that I'm missing but could not figure it out, thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Is your file really named `_ss_enviroment.php` or is that a typo? Because it should be enviro**n**ment

Comment: sorry typo here

Comment: Where do you run that `display` function?

Comment: in page.php class file, so eventually i decided just to declare dev enviroment in config php file like this `Director::set_environment_type('dev');` and this works for now.

Comment: If you're using SilverStripe 4, you will have an `.env` file which will sit in the root. `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` is the variable to change to `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"`   Reference: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/environment_management/

Comment: got you but using silverstripe 3

Comment: Are you actually 100% sure that file is read, eg its not reading some other environment file? if you add a die() or use xdebug or something to confirm the right environment file is loaded. E.g do you actually have the database configuration also in that file?